# Invisible Windows 8.1 custom-controls from Nuget when in designer mode

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, custom-controls, nuget, callisto

My custom control is invisible in Visual Studio and Blend designers when installed through Nuget. I suspect the reason behind this is that Generic.xaml had to be replaced with Generic.xbf when targeting Windows 8.1.

The [Callisto](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Callisto) library seems to share the same problem. Controls are invisible when in designer mode, but are perfectly functional when executed.

Can something be done about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Sigalas Unfortunately this is the case for NuGet packages.  There is a bit of a conflict right now where if the NuGet provider ships the XBF, then the designer suffers.  If you ship the XAML then you lose the performance benefits of XBF for the app.

For Callisto, I've chosen to optimize for the app performance for the benefit of all users of the app versus the benefit of the developer.  I'm working with the tools team to help improve this over time.

Using the Extension SDK method of shipping an SDK doesn't have this issue.

Comment: I was able to get the best of both worlds (as far as I can tell) by including both the .xaml and .xbf files side-by-side in the NuGet package.